# Табы на чистом Javascript + Aria

Tags: javascript, tab

Задумка у скрипта хорошая, но написан с ошибками. Помогите исправить ошибки в скрипте:

> Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null(…)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs" data-directive="tabs">
   <li><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container-tabs">

<section id="one">
<p>1</p>
</section>

<section id="two">
<p>2</p>
</section>

</div>
```

**js**

```
!function (t, e, i) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(i) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = i() : e[t] = i();
}("Tabs", this, function () {
    "use strict";
    function t(t) {
        var e, i;
        this.tabs = t.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=tab]");        
        for (this.target = t, this.panels = [], e = 0, i = this.tabs.length; i > e; e++)
            this.panels.push(document.getElementById(this.tabs[e].hash.replace("#", "")));
        void 0 === this.selectedIndex && this._init();
        for (var a = this.target.getElementsByTagName("li"), s = 0; s < a.length; s++)
            a[s].setAttribute('role', 'presentation');

    }
    return t.prototype._init = function () {
        var t, e = this;
        for (this.target.setAttribute("role", "tablist"), t = this.tabs.length - 1; t >= 0; t--) {
            var i = this.tabs[t], a = this.panels[t], s = 0 === t || window.location.hash.replace("#", "") == a.id;
            i.setAttribute("role", "tab"), i.setAttribute("aria-selected", s), i.setAttribute("aria-controls", i.hash.replace("#", "")), a.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel"), a.setAttribute("tabindex", "0"), a.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", i.hash.replace("#", "")), s ? this.selectedIndex = t : a.setAttribute("aria-hidden", !0);
        }
        this.clickHandler = function (t) {
            var i = t.srcElement || t.target;
            "tab" == i.getAttribute("role") && (t.preventDefault ? t.preventDefault() : t.returnValue = !1, e.toggle(i));
        }, this.keyHandler = function (t) {
            switch (t.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    e.tabs[e.selectedIndex - 1] && e.toggle(e.tabs[e.selectedIndex - 1]);
                    break;
                case 39:
                    e.tabs[e.selectedIndex + 1] && e.toggle(e.tabs[e.selectedIndex + 1]);
            }
        }, this.target.addEventListener ? (this.target.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler, !1), this.target.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyHandler, !1)) : (this.target.attachEvent("onclick", this.clickHandler), this.target.attachEvent("onclick", this.keyHandler));
    }, t.prototype.toggle = function (t) {
        var e, i, a = document.getElementById(t.hash.replace("#", ""));
        for (t.focus(), this.tabs[this.selectedIndex].setAttribute("aria-selected", !1), this.panels[this.selectedIndex].setAttribute("aria-hidden", !0), t.setAttribute("aria-selected", !0), a.setAttribute("aria-hidden", !1), e = 0, i = this.tabs.length; i > e && t != this.tabs[e]; e++)
            ;
        this.selectedIndex = e;
    }, t.prototype.teardown = function () {
        var t, e;
        this.target.removeAttribute("role");
        for (this.target.removeEventListener ? (this.target.removeEventListener("click", this.clickHandler, !1), this.target.removeEventListener("click", this.keyHandler, !1)) : (this.target.detachEvent("onclick", this.clickHandler), this.target.detachEvent("onclick", this.keyHandler)), t = 0, e = this.tabs.length; e > t; t++) {
            var i = this.tabs[t], a = this.panels[t];
            i.removeAttribute("role"), i.removeAttribute("aria-selected"), i.removeAttribute("aria-controls"), a.setAttribute("aria-hidden", !1), a.removeAttribute("role");
        }
        delete this.selectedIndex;
    }, t;

});
var instance = new Tabs(document.querySelector("[data-directive=tabs]"));
var instance = new Tabs(document.querySelector("[data-directive=tabs-2]"));
var instance = new Tabs(document.querySelector("[data-directive=tabs-3]"));
var instance = new Tabs(document.querySelector("[data-directive=tabs-4]"));

var r = document.querySelector('.container-tabs');
    r.setAttribute('aria-live', 'polite'), r.setAttribute('role', 'region');
```

Comment: _function t(t) {_ -вот так лучше не делать

Comment: а откуда у тебя этот скрипт?

Comment: проблема заключается в том, что у тебя в разметке нет элементов с _[data-directive=tabs-2]_ и т.д. `document.querySelector` возвращает в этом случае `null`, Поэтому и падает все внутри функции

Comment: Обилие однобуквенных переменных (для хранения всего подрят, а не только счетчиков), наводит на мысль что вы пишете сразу обфусцированный код. Хотя, у вас это плохо получается, код всё ещё можно прочесть. Чтобы запутать его ещё сильнее рекомендую дом функции тоже обфусцировать, к примеру весто `this.target.getElementsByTagName(...)` определите гденить переменную `u="getElementsByTagName"` и пишите `this.target[u](...)`.

Comment: @Arnial, а мне всегда казалось что обфускацию делают скрипты/программы, а не человек :D а однобуквенные переменные просто признак плохого кода :) Или это у вас такой сарказм? :)

Comment: @gil9red, скорее просто минифицированная версия прогнанная через beautifier

Comment: Скрипт собрал сам из кусков кода. [data-directive=tabs-2] - это для второй и следующих табов на одной странице.

Comment: @Viher, вот у тебя их нет, поэтому все и падает, как только добавишь их в разметку все должно заработать, либо как только уберешь их из скрипта

Comment: Grundy, да точно, тогда как без ошибок определить селектор для остальных табов на одной странице?

Comment: мне кажется из предыдущих комментариев стало понятно как это работает :-) у тебя есть скрипт, есть разметка, в скрипет указано какие табы создавать, если в разметке нет указанных табов - будет ошибка.

Comment: не правда, табы есть - указаны, но ошибка :)

Comment: какие ваши доказательства? :-) если ошибка - значит их нет. Все просто. Как минимум их нет на момент вызова `document.querySelector`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47600/discussion-between-viher-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось в комментариях, проблема в том, что один и тот же скрипт подключается на разные страницы с разными наборами табов.

Для решения проблемы достаточно выделить саму инициализацию в отдельный файл:

```
!function (t, e, i) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(i) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = i() : e[t] = i();
}("Tabs", this, function () {
    "use strict";
    function t(t) {
        var e, i;
        this.tabs = t.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=tab]");        
        for (this.target = t, this.panels = [], e = 0, i = this.tabs.length; i > e; e++)
            this.panels.push(document.getElementById(this.tabs[e].hash.replace("#", "")));
        void 0 === this.selectedIndex && this._init();
        for (var a = this.target.getElementsByTagName("li"), s = 0; s < a.length; s++)
            a[s].setAttribute('role', 'presentation');

    }
    return t.prototype._init = function () {
        var t, e = this;
        for (this.target.setAttribute("role", "tablist"), t = this.tabs.length - 1; t >= 0; t--) {
            var i = this.tabs[t], a = this.panels[t], s = 0 === t || window.location.hash.replace("#", "") == a.id;
            i.setAttribute("role", "tab"), i.setAttribute("aria-selected", s), i.setAttribute("aria-controls", i.hash.replace("#", "")), a.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel"), a.setAttribute("tabindex", "0"), a.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", i.hash.replace("#", "")), s ? this.selectedIndex = t : a.setAttribute("aria-hidden", !0);
        }
        this.clickHandler = function (t) {
            var i = t.srcElement || t.target;
            "tab" == i.getAttribute("role") && (t.preventDefault ? t.preventDefault() : t.returnValue = !1, e.toggle(i));
        }, this.keyHandler = function (t) {
            switch (t.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    e.tabs[e.selectedIndex - 1] && e.toggle(e.tabs[e.selectedIndex - 1]);
                    break;
                case 39:
                    e.tabs[e.selectedIndex + 1] && e.toggle(e.tabs[e.selectedIndex + 1]);
            }
        }, this.target.addEventListener ? (this.target.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler, !1), this.target.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyHandler, !1)) : (this.target.attachEvent("onclick", this.clickHandler), this.target.attachEvent("onclick", this.keyHandler));
    }, t.prototype.toggle = function (t) {
        var e, i, a = document.getElementById(t.hash.replace("#", ""));
        for (t.focus(), this.tabs[this.selectedIndex].setAttribute("aria-selected", !1), this.panels[this.selectedIndex].setAttribute("aria-hidden", !0), t.setAttribute("aria-selected", !0), a.setAttribute("aria-hidden", !1), e = 0, i = this.tabs.length; i > e && t != this.tabs[e]; e++)
            ;
        this.selectedIndex = e;
    }, t.prototype.teardown = function () {
        var t, e;
        this.target.removeAttribute("role");
        for (this.target.removeEventListener ? (this.target.removeEventListener("click", this.clickHandler, !1), this.target.removeEventListener("click", this.keyHandler, !1)) : (this.target.detachEvent("onclick", this.clickHandler), this.target.detachEvent("onclick", this.keyHandler)), t = 0, e = this.tabs.length; e > t; t++) {
            var i = this.tabs[t], a = this.panels[t];
            i.removeAttribute("role"), i.removeAttribute("aria-selected"), i.removeAttribute("aria-controls"), a.setAttribute("aria-hidden", !1), a.removeAttribute("role");
        }
        delete this.selectedIndex;
    }, t;

});
```

Который подключать "как есть" к страницам на которых нужны табы.

И на конкретной странице выполнять дополнительный код, например если на странице табы с селекторами "[data-directive=tabs]" и "[data-directive=tabs-2]", То достаточно применять библиотеку **только** для них

```
var instance = new Tabs(document.querySelector("[data-directive=tabs]"));
var instance2 = new Tabs(document.querySelector("[data-directive=tabs-2]"));
```

По аналогии стоит сделать и с другими страницами. Чтобы экземпляры создавались только для элементов, которые находятся на странице. В противном случае будет ошибка указанная в вопросе.